# File exists always returning false

Tags: php, file-exists

My image directory is `\webroot\files\thumbs`

I am trying to add `file_exists` condition. For that I tried bellow code

```
$file = WWW_ROOT .'files' . DS . 'thumbs' . DS .'_'.$password->collection_id.'jpg';

$file_exists = file_exists($file);
```

It's always returning zero.

If I `echo $file` it's giving me output like this

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\files\thumbs\_61.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `.` before the extension.  Update your `$file` definition as follows:

```
$file = WWW_ROOT .'files' . DS . 'thumbs' . DS .'_'.$password->collection_id.'.jpg';
                                                       // This was missing ---^

$file_exists = file_exists($file);
```